# Weirdness when clicking span elements

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-rc

I have a FAYT input I'm checking. I type in the textbox, see the options unfold and click one of them. All this passes neatly but there is something in the process that fails because the selected category is not selected. (this feature works like a charm when you try it manually)

This is the outline of the drop down suggestions' html:

```
<div id="suggestions">
   <span name="span1" onclick="selectByClick()" onMouseOver="changeColor()">text1<span/>
   <span name="span2" onclick="selectByClick()" onMouseOver="changeColor()">text2<span/>
</div>
```

What I'm doing is:

```
sel.click('//div[@id="suggestions"]//span[2]')
```

Ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it:

```
sel.mouse_over(xpath)
sel.click(xpath)
```